# fused location provider give wrong location

Tags: android, fusedlocationproviderapi

i am using Fusedlocationprovider get my current location, Some times I get the current location currently ,but some times give wrong location ,but near the current location. what is the reason, I am new to android , help me to solve this problem.thank you.

**This is the my code :**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {


    private FusedLocationProviderApi locationProvider = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi;
    private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
    private LocationRequest locationRequest;
    private double myLatitude;
    private double myLongitude;
    private static final int MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION = 101;
    private static final int MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION = 102;
    private boolean permissionIsGranted = false;
    String phonenumber;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            phonenumber = extras.getString("key11");
            getIntent().removeExtra("key11");
        }

        googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();

        locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        locationRequest.setInterval(10 * 1000);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(15 * 1000);
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);


    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        requestLocationUpdates();
    }

    private void requestLocationUpdates() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION);
            } else {
                permissionIsGranted = true;
            }
            return;
        }
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, locationRequest, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        myLatitude = location.getLatitude();
        myLongitude = location.getLongitude();

        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        smsManager.sendTextMessage(phonenumber, null, "*-"+String.valueOf(myLatitude)+"@"+String.valueOf(myLongitude)+"@", null, null);

        System.exit(0);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        googleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (permissionIsGranted) {
            if (googleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                requestLocationUpdates();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (permissionIsGranted)
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (permissionIsGranted)
            googleApiClient.disconnect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION:
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // permission granted
                    permissionIsGranted = true;
                } else {
                    //permission denied
                    permissionIsGranted = false;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "This app requires location permission to be granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
                break;
            case MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION:
                // do something for coarse location
                break;
        }
    }

}
```

Please help me Android Pro Developers Solve my error!

Comment: my be its happening because of your device is moving and i think FusedLocationProviderApi is deprecated now you should use FusedLocationProviderClient .

Comment: recently i worked on that here - https://github.com/kdblue/GetMyCurrentLocation ,i hope its help you .

Comment: I found the reasion.the reasion was  System.exit(0); I comment it.then give currect location.but now I have another problem.thai is location is send me every time.how can I stop it?

Comment: working 20 hours every day, thats amazing Never Give Up !